# How to align an img and a carousel next to each other, with max-width of 1000px?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and I've ran into an obstacle while trying to align the img (`#logo`) and the carousel (`#my-slider`) - both located in `#img-header`.

Under them there is a navigation bar and under that some text. The site is supposed to hava a max-width of 1000px (the width of the img is 350px and the width of carousel is 630px, so supposably they're both under 1000px), however when trying to align them, carousel jumps under the logo. If I try to align just the carousel with the navbar and text, `float:left` works (if I change the max-width to 1060) however, `float:right` does not work at all - it moves to the right, no matter how i change the max-width. All 3, navbar, text and img-header are supposed to be equally wide. The img and carousel "agree" to be in the same line only if I set the max-width to 1880, which also makes the stick to the left and not being centered. I also tried setting the `max-width` to 1000 and float the logo to left and carousel to right but it also doesn't work - neither does it work if I float both to the same side (for example, both `float:left;`.

[This is how the website is supposed to look like- with this in the center.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hA7I.png)

[Demo of the website](https://jsfiddle.net/hos82nv1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="img-header">
    <img id="logo" src="logo/logo3.png" style="width:350px;height:240px"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class"row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="my-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:630px;height:240px">

                    <!-- indicators, small dots -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listenbox">
                        <div class="item active">  
                            <img src="food/food1.jpg" alt="food 1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">  
                            <img src="food/food2.jpg" alt="food 2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">  
                            <img src="food/food3.jpg" alt="food 3">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--navigations/ next and prev buttons --> 
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <!--<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>-->
                    </a>

                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <!--<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>-->
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#img-header {
max-width: 1060px ;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;   
}   


#logo {
float: left;
} 
 #my-slider {
float: left;
}
 #navbar {
max-width: 1000px ;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
}
 ul {
list-style-type: none;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #125ea3;
}
li {
float: right ;  
}
li:last-child {
border-right: none;
}
li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #3594ff;
}
.active {
background-color: #3594ff;
}
.text {
max-width: 1000px ;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
}
h1 {
text-align="center"
}
p {
text-align="center"
}
```

I know I am just a begginer so I have probably made quite a few mistakes, please forgive me in advance.

Thanks for all the help and advice in advance!

Comment: Please provide demo.

Comment: Is this code complete? you have 5 closing </div> tags and only 1 opening <div> tag that is not closed

Comment: Forgive me, it's my first time using this website and I didn't notice not all of the code i pasted was showed.

Comment: Also, I provided a demo :)

Comment: What is the end result supposed to look like? Where is it supposed to be aligned? Perhaps a picture or diagram to show your intent would prove useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation of bootstrap has everything. You just need to look for it. 
http://getbootstrap.com/css"

And I think your problem can be solved by

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <!--Logo Comes here-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
     <!--Carousal Comes here-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much! after playing with the size of my elements, that worked. thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

**You've got Probs:**
I think I've uncovered some of your main issues. First off, you had a typo (missing `=` 'equals sign') for your `div.row`'s class declaration.

The biggest issue for this is your structure. I suggest you do some further reading on bootstrap and how it works with the below links.

Also, I've had trouble identifying what your main goal was regarding responsivity, so you have 3 versions that all do different things. Let me know if I made a typo or forgot about something.

---

**Here's what I did:**

I went ahead and rebuilt your `HTML` structure using a generator (linked below). I figured this would be okay since you probably should re-build (**yes, again, and on your own using the documentation if you want to learn how things work**) the layout a 2nd time anyways.

---

**Demos:**

- `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjdRJK` (Version 1)
- `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QExPmP` (Version 2)
- `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzaLwk` (Version 3)

  ---

**Further Reading:**

- http://www.layoutit.com/build      (used generator system)
- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid  (**read this please**)
- http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ (customize `Bootstrap` here)
- Quick breakdown of `Bootstrap`     (below)

  ---

### **Quick Breakdown of `Bootstrap`:**

`Bootstrap` is a really nifty system, but I often see it get overcomplicated and used incorrectly thereafter. I think it'd be helpful if we simplified things regarding what `Bootstrap` actually is in order to bring some clarity to the issue. I'll write more if requested.

First off:

- `Bootstrap` is a **`framework`**:

  - This means that `Bootstrap` is simply *just a pre-made foundational structure* that your code is built off of.
  - This *also* means that `Bootstrap` is intended to be **customized**. This link will show you that: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ (also placed in the list for convenience)
- Go ahead and click on that link and note how the 'customizer' actually works. It's essentially a really big form that you fill out which sets variables  to appropriately change the downloadable package's contents. You'll see that one  of the very first sections is a variety of checkboxes that allows you to *not only change* their settings/formats/etc., but **also** remove specific components *entirely*, like `jQuery` plugins or `Javascript` `Component`s.
- Bootstrap covers `HTML`, `CSS`, and `Javascript`

> **Consider this Analogy**: it's best to use a concrete foundation to construct a building upon - *although it's certainly possible to build* a house without a rock-solid, ground-embedded concrete base of a foundation, it certainly won't adapt to & survive the future storms of obsoletion and changes to the land.
>
> **The meaning behind it:** Not that it's impossible to create a great front-end presentation without them, but frameworks like `Bootstrap` totally rock. They address a multitude of potential issues and problems related to possibly unexpected results, they take care of a lot of the repeated, preamblic code, and they're incredibly flexible: able to be customized, reduced, enhanced, etc.
>
> **Often Overlooked**: One hidden `gem`/benefit is that `Bootstrap` (much like every other widely-used `framework`/system, like `Drupal`, `Magento`, or `Wordpress`) inherently creates a reliably (usually) consistent set of standards that aren't only easy for (almost) everyone to adhere to (most without even knowing it) but are also easy for (almost) everyone to understand (like when debugging for others on StackOverflow).

## **Here's the key**:

`Bootstrap` simply has a bunch of extra stuff: they don't know exactly what you'll need for whatever you're doing, **but they've made a pretty good assumption that it'll undoubtedly include usage of** the `grid` system, `image`s, and a few `component`s like `jumbotron`s or `callout`s. The option is left up to you what you do (and) don't include in your Customized `Bootstrap` download.

And that's it. Those are the basics. Nothing crazy to it except some fantastic innovative insight, courtesy of its creator(s). Though it handles a LOT more than your trusty ol'e `CSS Reset` and `CSS Normalize`, it's quite a bit less intimidating if you treat it like a `CSS Reset` on super code steroids.

That's all!

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and explaining bootstrap!! This will surely help me on my ongoing journey a lot! Thanks again!! :) xx

Comment: Glad to be of service. Was anything written in a confusing way? I tried breaking it down as much as possible

Comment: No, everything is perfectly fine :) Now i just have to make it look ok on the phone as well :)